# Create an event in an input (angular 4+)

Tags: angular, angular4-forms, angular-template

I apologize in advance for my English and hope to make myself understood.

I have a form and I would like the user to add a date in an input, and the `/` of I add by myself. The code works very well because it is displayed correctly in the `console`. But it is impossible to reproduce this in the input(type = text).

here is the component.ts:

```
ngOnInit() {
 this.changes()
 }

changes() {
this.petForm.controls.birthday.valueChanges
.subscribe(res => {
  const resLength = res.length
  if(resLength < 6 ) {
    res.replace(/(..)/g, '$1/')
  }
})
}
```

In the `console` no problem here's what it looks like:
[image]

Here the template:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="birthday" class="size0">{{ 'PARTNER.bday_placeholder' | 
  translate}} *</label>
  <input 
  class="input--default input__signup__default" 
  formControlName="birthday" 
  type="text" 
  placeholder="{{'PARTNER.bday_placeholder' | translate}} *"
  required>  
</div>
```

I hope I was able to explain my problem and that you were able to understand me. Thank you to those who are trying to solve this small problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For reactive form, you cannot just update the value like how you do it.
Instead of

```
res.replace(/(..)/g, '$1/')
```

Should be:

```
this.petForm.controls.birthday.setValue(res.replace(/(..)/g, '$1/'), {
      emitEvent: false
    });
```

Take note of the `setValue` second params, I pass in `emitEvent: false` to not trigger value changes event. Else your code might end up infinite loop.

Example url: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-amqta3

Comment: @mathiaF You dont need to do anything on html side

Comment: You don't need to do anything on html side as @Manzurul mentioned. I updated the answer with an example url

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. However, this does not always work. Even if it's a good start, I'm displaying something:)

Comment: yup, there's something you need to do in your regex. :) The answer that I provided is solving the part which updating form value only.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it. But it's good thanks to you it works well, I just can't get rid of the slash yet. But it's not much, I think.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the subscription and try this:
**HTML:**

```
<input .... #birthday (input)="birthday.value=changeValue(birthday.value)" ....>
```

**Typescript:**

```
changeValue(value){
  const resLength = value.length;
  if(resLength < 6 ) {
    return value.replace(/(..)/g, '$1/');
  }
  return value;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, for the moment it doesn't work but I'm almost there with your solution. Thank you

Comment: I'll try to put it on plunker:)